# Inject javascript with jquery in webview android

Tags: android, android-webview

I want to inject some javascript functions with jquery in android WebView.

What exactly I want to do is like, 
I load one URL in android WebView and in that I want to inject some javascript function with jquery which I already have with me.

I don't want to add any HTML with javascript.

below function, I want to inject in WebView.

```
$("form").each(function (index) {
        $(this).find("input").not(":input[type=radio]").not(":input[type=checkbox]").each(function (index) {
//enter code here
            });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
                   webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
                   webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
                      override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView, url: String) {
                        injectJS()
                     }
                   }
                   webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com")





>   **We will use JavaScript to change some of the UI properties for
> google.com website, so the obvious thing we need to do is to allow
> webView to use JavaScript.**
```

```
        function () {
          document.getElementById("hplogo").src = "https://android.com.pl/images/user-images/2017/03/android-developer2.png";
          document.bgColor = "#454343";
          document.getElementById("lst-ib").value = "Some random text";
        }
```

> **Our JS function is really simple. Using DOM allows to change some
>   of the website properties in few lines of code! In Java we usually use
>   this to read XML files, but if you are not familiar with it - check
>   this tutorial. It is very important to call injectJS() after website
>   is fully loaded, because in this case JS function is based on already
>   created elements of website. However, this does not prevent you from
>   using jQuery or any other JS framework that you are familiar with.**

```
        private fun injectJS() {
                try {
                    val inputStream = assets.open("style.js")
                    inputStream.bufferedReader().use(BufferedReader::readText)
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    null
                }?.let { webView.loadUrl("javascript:($it)()")  }
            }
```

Comment: this injects pure javascript function. check my updated question.